# structs and pointers. unclear output

Tags: c

can someone please explain to me why is the output of the following code 6 and not 5? i do not understand how calling hoo changed the value of m->x.
even after running the code and following each step of it, it is still not clear to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct a {
    int x;
    struct a* next;
}a_t;

a_t* foo() {
    a_t* varp, var = { 5,NULL };
    varp = &var;
    return varp;
}

a_t* hoo() {
    a_t* varp, var = { 6,NULL };
    varp = &var;
    return varp;
}

void main()
{
    a_t* m = foo();
    hoo();
    printf("%d", m->x);
}
```

Comment: Your code is undefined behavior.

Comment: `var.x` is invalid outside `foo`.

Comment: Because you can't return a local variable from a function. Your pointer points to data that has been deallocated when you try to access it. There are many duplicates on SO.

Comment: and it's just a coincidence that the deallocated memory of the var in foo has been used for the var in hoo so that the data left in the adress is 6?

Comment: Yes, your last statement is correct. You got lucky but try adding a few other lines of code to your program and see what happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions `hoo` and `foo` are returning pointers to local variables which is by definition *undefined behavior`.

They both implement different structures (2 copies) and you are printing value from first one.

Since you first created structure on stack with function `foo`, you had lucky and function `hoo` also created function on the stack on the same place.

Therefore you had override.

If you want to return pointer from function, use either `static` or allocate memory dynamically on heap using `malloc`.

```
a_t* foo() {
    a_t* varp = malloc(sizeof(*varp));
    varp->m = 5;
    return varp;
}

void main()
{
    a_t* m = foo();
    hoo();
    printf("%d", m->x);
    free(m);
}
```

Now you are allocating memory outside stack and it will work as you expected.

Comment: thank you for the clear answer. the code is wrong on purpose it's part of an exercise i found. i just didn't have any explanation for the output and wanted to learn what exactly happens in the memory.

Comment: Returning pointers to local variables does not, in itself, cause undefined behaviour.   Any attempt by the caller to dereference such pointers does.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior. Let's see why.

```
a_t* foo() {
    // creates a variable on the stack
    a_t* varp, var = { 5,NULL };
    // sets address of variable on stack to another variable on the stack
    varp = &var;
    // you return that address on the stack
    return varp;
}

a_t* hoo() {
    // creates a variable on the stack
    a_t* varp, var = { 6,NULL };
    // sets address of variable on stack to another variable on the stack
    varp = &var;
    // you return that address on the stack
    return varp;
}
```

Why is the following code above cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)? You're returning variables (that contain addresses) that you don't own anymore after the end of the function calls for `hoo` and `foo`.
The system owns that memory now!
Computers are stupid and will blindly execute any command you give them. I think you intended to use [malloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) to save the variables you wanted to persist outside of the function call to the heap.

```
a_t* foo() {
    a_t *varp = malloc(sizeof(struct a_t));
    varp->x = 5;
    varp->next = NULL;
    return varp;
}
```

Can you fix the other one?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you called hoo() you created a different varp and var than the ones you created before using foo and storing it in the variable m. However, this new varp is being created on the same memory address as the varp of m and overriding its value.

If you go line by line using F5 and adding 3 break points on the lines in main, add a watch on the variable m and then step into hoo() and notice the memory address assigned to varp is the same as that of m... So when you leave hoo() and go back to main you will lose the value stored in m as it has been overwritten[notice the cursor is still at line 22 and didn't overwrite yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE9Qn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can define “static var...”. 
So var is will be still alive after the function return.